# laravel cors "Class cors does not exist" error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cors

I have followed https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors to enable CORS on my application.

When I refresh my page (REST endpoint), I get the following message :-

```
Class cors does not exist
```

I ran the following command :-

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors 0.7.x
```

and have the following line in my composer.json

```
"barryvdh/laravel-cors": "0.7.x"
```

Routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function($router){
    $router->get('names/{id}', 'NameController@showEmpDetail');
    $router->resource('names', 'NameController');
});
```

I am guessing that somewhere I'll need to call the package, like use the package etc..but I am not finding any result to help me out.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the serviceprovider `'Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors',` to your `config/app.php` file?

Answer (score 11):

Try to add

```
 'cors' => \Barryvdh\Cors\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
```

to

```
 /app/Http/Kernel.php $routeMiddleware
```

Answer (score 9):

The readme.md at https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors is missing a few steps for Laravel 5.  Here are the complete instructions:

- `composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors 0.7.x`
- `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"` or copy `vendor/barryvdh/laravel-cors/config/cors.php` to `config/cors.php`
- config/app.php -> 'providers': `Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class`
- app/Http/Kernel.php -> $routeMiddleware: `'cors' => \Barryvdh\Cors\Middleware\HandleCors::class`
- `php artisan cache:clear` (<- if needed)

Now the cors middleware will work for your routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(Router $router){
    $router->get('api', 'ApiController@index'); // <- your route here
});
```

Comment: I can confirm that this answer still applies to Laravel 5.5.19

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem when upgrading from laravel 8 to laravel 9. So first of I remove the barryvdh/laravel-cors package and install fruitcake/laravel-cors. It solves the problem.

```
composer remove barryvdh/laravel-cors fruitcake/laravel-cors
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

You can check the git repo of [fruitcake/laravel-cors](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors).

Comment: Thank you!...you just saved my night

Answer (score 5):

If you upgrade to Laravel 9, 10 or higher the steps are explained here:
https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Short version:

1. Remove "fruitcake/laravel-cors" from your composer.json
2. Replace \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class, with \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class, in app/Http/Kernel.php

Answer (score 2):

just delete cors from protected $middlewareGroups in app/Http/kernel.php

Answer (score 1):

For me in Laravel 7 below code is working

You need to change in "app\Http\Kernel.php" file
In $routeMiddleware

You need to Write:

```
'cors' => \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
```

Instead of

```
'cors' => \Barryvdh\Cors\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
```

and If you are using API's then

```
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command in terminal

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I had messed up few files, and then was greeted with this error.

Things worked for me

`1. Delete the vendor folder`

`2. composer install`

`3. php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command it will solve your issue.

```
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your mapApiRoutes() method in app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php, to this, do not put 'cors' in the prefix function, just put only 'api' as the parameter

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```